# Does svn import obey the svn propedit svn:ignore

Tags: svn, version-control, import, repository

I have an empty repo and I'm doing an

```
 svn import /var/www/source_proj/ svn:///ipaddress//var/www/proj/ -m "First Import"
```

but it seems to be 'Adding' all the files I told it not to. Is it actually adding the files?I can't wait till the adding proccess is complete because its Gigabytes of small unwanted files in a directory.

I did a svn propedit svn:ignore .
for

```
proj/sites/default/files
proj/sites/all/all-files
```

but i still see stuff like

```
Adding         source_proj/sites/all/all-files/2011-06-13/list_a85705_2011-06-13.csv
Adding         source_proj/sites/all/all-files/2011-06-13/list_a97207_2011-06-13.csv
Adding         source_proj/sites/all/all-files/2011-06-13/list_a24983_2011-06-13.csv
```

Alternatively if I knew to just transform an existing directory into a repository that would be good, using a previously blank repo then committing all the new, unignored files.

Answer (score 0):

For  `svn import [PATH] URL` PATH is expected to be plain, unversioned tree. None of SVN features are awaited and processed.

If you want to commit Working Copy to new, different repo you have (can) to use relocate-commit (if UUID-problem doesn't block it)